# Does ST_ClusterKMeans benefit from a spatial index?

Tags: postgis, clustering

Does ST_ClusterKMeans benefit from a spatial index? here is how I am using it (24313 is projection in meters):

```
    ST_ClusterKMeans(
                ST_Transform(d.bf_polygon, 24313),
                1,
                50
            ) OVER 

(PARTITION BY d.settlement_id ORDER BY d.bf_id) AS cluster_id
```

Comment: Why not try it? Have you tried running it with and without a spatial index?

Comment: because it would need a lot of last minute code changes! so would only proceed if it is worth it.

Comment: Just run `explain analyse` on that query and then add a spatial index and repeat no new code needed

Comment: You should at least benefit from an index for the transform `create index blah_trans_idx on blah using gist((st_transform(bf_polygon, 24313)))`